1980s or 90s space cartoon with a space prince and princess
I saw it in the 90s on a VHS. I think it's an 80s cartoon. This is what I remember of it:

A space prince all dressed in blue, looked like a skinny version of He-Man with brown hair. A space princess all dressed in pink with red hair, skinny. An evil queen/witch all dressed in green. The prince comes from one planet and the princess had to flee her planet, because the evil witch/queen has taken it under her control.

There is an amphibian-like side character, light green, called Podok, who can stretch his body. I also think there is a squirrel character.

On the VHS tape, the prince, princess, Podok and the squirrel travel to a planet with lots of dragons. They crash their spaceship in a mud lake, much like in Star Wars. At some point in the episode or perhaps a different one, they end up in a house/palace with robots that shoot laser beams out of their eyes. The robots awaken when they accidentally activate some trap in a room with a treasure pile.



This you as well? https://www.reddit.com/r/oldcartoons/comments/11vi9c4/which_8090s_cartoon/

Bits of this sound like Voltron; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyhVz0ecv-Q&list=PLfWZ527dWURa8MOqqTWrYIp0IRqimiqhO

https://voltron.fandom.com/wiki/Prorok

The fact that a promising-looking answer was posted using a spanish-language show points out that this question (and others like it) should really include some inkling of where you physically saw it. TV I take it, but what country were you living in at the time? Was it an English language show? A lot of times when I see a question like this, I might assume it was a show you watched from a broadcast on American TV. If you know that wasn't the case, you could save a lot of people a lot of time.

... If you know it was the case, you could have saved @LogicDictates a lot of time.

Is this La corona mágica (1989-1990)...?
It's a 26-episode Spanish-language animated series featuring a blend of science fiction (such as spaceships and robots) and medieval fantasy (such as sorcery and dragons).
From Wikipedia (auto-translated from Spanish):

The story takes place in the imaginary Double Sun System, made up of seven planets and twelve moons. The planet closest to the two suns is uninhabited; the second desert; the third, called Brigabor, is ruled by King Brigal and his son, Prince Zalk and its inhabitants dwell in peace. Rahman, the greatest magician in the Kingdom, is in charge of guarding the Magic Crown, a mysterious crown with incredible powers, which maintains the balance of forces in the Double Sun System.
The last three planets of the system, the so-called Lost Planets, are ruled by the evil witch Idun and her army, commanded by the vizier Zohak. Idun will try to get the Magic Crown to take control of the galaxy but Zalk and his friends will try to stop him.

The characters you described would presumably be Prince Zalk, Princess Shaila, Queen Idún, Potok and Shais.
Zalk wears blue and has brown hair.

Prince Zalk: Son of King Brigal and heir to the throne of the planet Brigabor, as well as the Double Sun System, he is an adventurous and somewhat impetuous young man. Even so, he is brave and loyal to his friends. He is always backed and protected by Rahman.


Shaila wears pink and has red hair.

Shaila: Princess of the Desert Planet, which Zalk and the other inhabitants of Brigabor assumed to be devoid of life. Bold, loyal and with a high sense of justice, although sometimes a little stubborn. Although her people are initially suspicious of them, she trusts Zalk from the beginning and helps them in their mission to defeat Idún. She and Zalk soon fall in love.


Idún wears green.

Queen Idún: Ruler of the Lost Planets (Iduanor, Kotuanor, and Kalahati) and the Black Planet, she is also a witch of great power and malice. As ambitious and cold as she is cruel and ruthless, she seeks to get hold of the Magic Crown, which is in the possession of the Brigal King, to increase her powers and defeat the king.


Potok is a type of tadpole and can stretch his body and limbs like Marvel's Mr. Fantastic, while Shais is a type of squirrel.

Potok and Shais: They are Zalk and Hanstor's small pets. Potok is a small tadpole apparently without arms (although he sometimes flaunts them) while Shais is a species of squirrel with large orange eyes.


In episode 5, "El planeta negro," the protagonists get stuck in a swamp and Potok saves them by leaping onto a tree branch then extending his arms like vines to pull them out. Later in the episode, they're attacked by a group of dragons.
In episode 6, "La ciudad perdida," the protagonists enter a lost city and find a large room with a huge pile of gold and several inactive robots in it. Then the robots come to life and start attacking them (but don't shoot lasers from their eyes or anywhere else).
If you live in Spain or have a VPN, all 26 episodes can be watched for free (in Spanish) here.



